# Papyrus SysML UML how to hide numbers next to the composition or aggregation line

Tags: uml, papyrus, sysml

I want to draw a block definition diagram and there are some lines for aggregation and composition. But I don't need the numbers next to the lines like `0..1` or `1`.  I want the line to be just the straight line, without any numbers next to it. Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARmU5bWoB8M&ab_channel=SpecificationofEmbeddedSystems

I found the link and follow the steps. Just right click the line and the last 3 options are for the labels. You can hide all of them or display all of them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).